# Bootstrapping data in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've manage to put together the below code through various examples, which seems to work okay, but it doesn't seem to preload my data, can anyone please tell me what I'm missing?

```
App = (function(Backbone, _){
    var Note = Backbone.Model.extend(
    {
        defaults:
        {
            part1: 'hello',
            part2: 'world'
        }
    });

    var TableList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Note
    });

    var ListRow = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        tagName: 'li',

        initialize: function()
        {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },

        render: function()
        {
            $(this.el).html('<span>'+this.model.get('part1')+' '+this.model.get('part2')+'</span>');

            return this;
        }
    });

    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        el: $('#layout_content'),

        events:
        {
            'click button#add': 'addItem'
        },

        initialize: function()
        {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem', 'appendItem');

            this.collection = new TableList();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);

            this.counter = 0;
            this.render();
        },

        render: function()
        {
            var self = this;
            $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add list item</button>");

            $(this.el).append("<ul></ul>");

            _(this.collection.models).each(function(item){ // in case collection is not empty
                self.appendItem(item);
            }, this);
        },

        addItem: function()
        {
            this.counter++;

            var note = new Note();

            note.set({part2: note.get('part2') + this.counter});

            this.collection.add(note);
        },

        appendItem: function(item)
        {
            var listRow = new ListRow({
                model: item
            });

            $('ul', this.el).append(listRow.render().el);
        }
    });

    var app = function(initialModels)
    {
        this.start = function()
        {
            this.tableList = new TableList();
            this.listView = new ListView({collection: this.tableList});
            this.tableList.reset(initialModels);
        };
    };

  return app;
})(Backbone, _);
```

then init the app with:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var app = new App([{"id":"95","note_title":"can we find the title"},{"id":"93","note_title":"some title"}]);
    app.start();
</script>
```

Comment: show us what the php code renders actually , and whaterror do you get in the browser's console.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the example with some hard coded values on the init.  Also no errors in the console.

Comment: Do you have an element with #layout_content in your html or are you expecting Backbone to create this element for you? You need an existing element #layout_content

Comment: yep, it's there, when I hit the "Add list item" button it all works, just can't get it to preload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, there are a few issues with your code,

there are 2 issues in your start method,

a) you throw away your collection

```
this.start = function()
{
    this.tableList = new TableList();
    this.listView = new ListView({collection: this.tableList});
    this.tableList.reset(initialModels);
};
```

and then in intialize is where you overwrite the collection you pass along

```
initialize: function()
{
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem', 'appendItem');
    this.collection = new TableList(); // this one gets overwritten, remove this line
}
```

b) you trigger a collection reset with the models you want to populate it with, but don't listen to an event, either add a listener like this:

```
this.collection.bind('reset', this.appendAllItems, this);
```

or create your collection like this:

```
this.start = function()
{
    this.tableList = new TableList(initialModels);
    this.listView = new ListView({collection: this.tableList});
};
```

Comment: commented out the line in the initialize function `this.collection = new TableList();`, but still no go.

Comment: I updated my answer in the meanwhile, note that your counter logic will not work in this case, You need to add the counter logic to the parse method and make sure you pass the option {parse: true} when you pass the initialModels

Comment: okay, got it with your second point.  I mistakenly made the connection that "reset" would trigger the "add" handler, makes sense now. Thanks!